# Why does Yii $model->save() fails when using a bogus email (with correct format)

Tags: php, validation, email, yii

As mentioned above.

Here's a snippet:

```
$model=SomeModel::model()->findByPk($someId);
$model->email = $_POST['email'];
$model->save();
```

When `$_POST['email']` is `test@asdf134.com` it fails.
When `$_POST['email']` is `test@hotmail.com` it is successful.

What could be wrong with this? Also it doesn't show any format error when I used `test@asdf134.com` and logs are exactly the same except for the emails set.

Does Yii authenticates email?

TIA

Comment: What are the rules you have in the model for email?  Also, is there any error on fail?

Comment: perhaps with validation rules, post your validation rules here...test@asdf134.com is not a valid email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting **checkMX** to *true* will force it to validate against DNS records.

http://www.haldwaniuk.in/validating-email-in-yii/

Comment: Thanks! This indeed clarifies everything and kudos to Yii Team for this wonderful feature. So to complement for this feature I enabled the `ajaxValidation` because my form is pointing to a different page which gets stuck when the validation fails.